# Appcelerator inactive for no reason?

Tags: appcelerator, billing

I've been and Indie developer for 10 months now, but today I can't login to Appcelerator Studio anymore.

When I look at the Appcelerator Dashboard, it says I'm inactive and my plan is set to Free Trial and it says it's expired. However in my payment history it says I've paid for all months (including the current month february)

The 'support' doesn't help much, they just say they've passed the issue to the billing people...

Anyone else have this problem?

Thanks,
Joost Anbeek (joost@distridata.nl)

Comment: This is not a programming question...this forum is for mainly technical queries..Kindly contact support staff of the Software

Answer (score 1):

After seeing you post here I checked my plan and saw it's being set to free trial as well. I just wrote support via that chat option on https://developer.appcelerator.com/ you get if you're logged in.
They just fixed it, without any hesitation. Just be patient.

Greeting Dom

Comment: Yes, you're right. They fixed it. It took some time, but now all is good. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome. 
Asked them what the problem was. They said it gave a delay in updating the accounts. Just for your information.